# Why word count DAG is different in pyspark than that of scala spark? Also please explain the DAG of pyspark for word count?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am new to Spark and using PySpark. I noticed difference in DAG of PySpark for word count program than Scala Spark. Can anyone help me understand that?

First DAG is PySpark

[image: DAG PySpark]

and second is Scala Spark

[image: DAG Scala]

Comment: In general it would be useful if you [edit] your question and include the [mcve] for both Scala and Python.

Comment: This is really an interesting question. Are you able to find the answer Vishal?

Answer (score 1):

That happens because, unlike `Dataset` / SQL API, which provides an uniform layer of execution for all supported languages, internal `RDD` API of the guest languages is language specific.

It means that it can use different internal logic, and can be scheduled in a different way.

Comment: It would be halpful if you can mention those differences or get me some source for the same.